# Adding a framework in Xcode

Tags: xcode, macos, frameworks

Im trying to add a third party framework in Xcode but I'm getting an error that it can't be found

> error: MKAbeFook/MKAbeFook.h: No Such File or Directory

I've added it in the Linked Frameworks group and added it to the Target for this project. I've also added it to a new Copy Files build phase for that target.

Basically I've followed the instructions here: http://pointlesscrap.net/mkabefook/desktop/gettingstarted

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 6):

Best way to diagnose this is to post the compiler invocation line, not just the error (you can just drag and drop the line from the Build Results window that says "Compiling foo.m").  My expectation is that you don't have a Frameworks Search Path set up for the location of the framework.  Xcode usually adds that manually when you add the framework, but if you put it in certain kinds of places, or added it in certain ways, you need to manually point your target's Framework Search Paths at its directory.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the author mistook MKFaceBook for MKAbeFook?

EDIT: Never mind, it looks like that is actully the name of the framework.